# Eclipse display short Classname even if exists multiple times

Tags: java, eclipse

Just a nice-to-have-feature, but is it possible to always display the short form of the class, even if the Classname is used multiple times from multiple packages?

Reason for this question is this:
I have a project with generated files from Webservices, in those webservices, Classes like "CodeType" are used over and over again in different packages.

My classes have to map the data, and so I have things like:

```
me.here.somewhere.elsewhere.this.that.CodeType codeType1 = new me.here.somewhere.elsewhere.this.that.CodeType();
me.here.somewhere.elsewhere.this.those.CodeType codeType2 = new me.here.somewhere.elsewhere.this.those.CodeType();
```

This makes the code extremly unreadable, I would like to display this as:

```
CodeType codeType1 = new CodeType();
CodeType codeType2 = new CodeType();
```

But only display it, I'm totally aware why the package has to be given and that this display wouldn't be "the real code" it would just be for readability. Something like "[x] collapsed packages".

I guess there isn't such an option?

Comment: You have 2 aspects in a language a lexer and a paser, a lexer provides "tokens" to the parser, the parser parser is the one how constructs the AST(before creating binary files). if you don't specify the package for 2 classes that have the same name, the parser couldn't distinguish between them.

Comment: I know, but the eclipse editor is just a display, it could present me the content in another way than the one on the disk. If I'm collapsing a comment, the editor hides the content, but is still exists in the file. My idea above was something like this, but for package-names.

Comment: No if you use Java editor then the instruction are parsed instantly.